# R add series of vectors to matrix and operate function with each addition

Tags: r, loops, matrix, vector, rbind

I have the following conundrum. The following piece of code, takes a vector, from a pool of vectors, rbinds the vector to the matrix and performs the function on the new matrix and returns a scalar result.

```
In2 <- diag(nXtr+1)
  mu <- array(1,c(dim(Xcal)[1],1))
  Y.hat.calib <- array(0,c(nC,1))  
  alpha <- array(0,c(nC,1))
  P = c()

  for (i in 1:dim(Xcal)[1]){
    Xtr2 <- rbind(Xtr,Xcal[i,])
    K2 <-(Xtr2%*%t(Xtr2)+1)^2
    rowCnt <- dim(Xtr2)[1]
    mu[i] <- sqrt(1 + t(c(rep(1,(rowCnt-1)),0))%*%solve(K2+a*In2)%*%K2%*%c(rep(0,(rowCnt-1)),1))

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    Y.hat.calib[i] <- kCal[,i]%*%solve(K + a*In)%*%Ytr
    alpha[i] <- (abs(Y.hat.calib[i] - Ycal[i]))/mu[i]
    P <- c(P,alpha[i])  
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have pre-allocated where needed, but really need to get rid of the loop as its too time consuming. I have played around with various ideas, bu cannot come up with a way to do this.

Any help would be gratefully received as always. if there is anything I have missed please let me know.

Comment: apologies, but the final curly brace has not been printed, rest assured that it is present! I should add also, that upon each iteration a new vector is added to the matrix and the function applied to the new matrix

Comment: I have looked at the do.call function also, but cannot see how it might be applied to this problem

Comment: Please add a sufficiently representative sample of data (`nXtr`, `Xcal`, `nC`, ...) so that others may run your code and dig into the problem.

Comment: sure, I'll put some together shortly

Comment: Okay, you should be able to just use `dput()` on the objects and copy & paste the output into your question.

Comment: I am not sure if dput() would be the best approach in this

Comment: Xcal is a 100 x 1024 matrix, nC=150, Xtr is a 300 x 1024 matrix. So at each iteration, Xtr becomes 101 x 1024 and a can be taken as equal to 1 for the moment

Comment: Thanks all for your input, much appreciated

Comment: No problem - `kCal` is a numeric matrix also I'm assuming; what is its dimension? And `nXtr`?

Comment: sorry, yes, kCal is also a matrix of dimension 200 x 1024 and nXtr is just the dim(Xtr)[1]

Comment: `kCal[,i]%*%solve(K + a*In)%*%Ytr` - is this supposed to be `K2` and `In2`, or are there two objects `K` and `In` you didn't mention?

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of `for` loops won't automatically make things faster. The biggest change you can make to your code is avoiding calculating `solve` whenever possible; `solve` is very computationally intense.

I didn't try to make sure that this was bug-free, because you hadn't provided sample data. But you can follow the general idea: don't do the `solve` in every loop, logically separate your calculation of `mu` from `alpha`, and replace column-by-column functions with matrix multiplication where you can.

```
# Your mu boils down to this:
get.mu <- function(Xcal.i, Xtr2=Xtr2, a.times.In2=a.times.In2) {  
  Xtr2 <- rbind(Xtr, Xcal.i) 
  K2 <-(Xtr2 %*% t(Xtr2) + 1)^2
  first.solve  <- solve(K2 + a.times.In2) %*% K2
  bread <- c(rep(1, nrow(Xtr2-1)), 0)
  sqrt(1 + t(bread) %*% first.solve  %*% bread) # mu
}

In2 <- diag(nXtr+1)
# Constants that you recalculated every loop.
a.times.In2 <- a*In2
second.solve <- solve(K  + a*In ) %*% Ytr
# Y.hat.calib can be fully calculated in one matrix multiplication.
Y.hat.calib <- kCal %*% second.solve
# Which means that the difference is a constant:
Y.diff <- abs(Y.hat.calib - Ycal)

# So alpha and mu could be calculated like:
mu <- apply(X.cal, 2, get.mu)
alpha <- t(t(Y.diff) / mu.i)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I'll take a look and compare with current results, also will post timings

Comment: Unless i am missing something, this code won't work as first.solve is not a constant, as K2 needs updating with Xcal.i

Comment: apologies, code needs re-formatting, I will enter it asap

Comment: Right. I corrected the code. It would have been easy to check this for bugs if you had provided small sample input data. Or some code to generate sample inputs.

Comment: cheers nograpes, I'll submit some data for next time. Your time is much appreciated